# Extend http on dont call request method in Angular 2

Tags: http, angular, jwt

I new in Angular 2 and i'm trying create an App with JWT. So, to do this I follow the post http://www.adonespitogo.com/articles/angular-2-extending-http-provider/.

But i'm a issue, the request method is never call, after login i have to refresh the page to send the token.

Here my classes

**http.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, XHRBackend, RequestOptions, Request, RequestOptionsArgs, Response, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';

@Injectable()
export class HttpService extends Http {

  constructor (backend: XHRBackend, options: RequestOptions) {    
    let token = localStorage.getItem('auth_token'); // your custom token getter function here
    options.headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`);
    options.headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    super(backend, options);
  }

  request(url: string | Request, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
    let token = localStorage.getItem('auth_token');
    if (typeof url === 'string') { // meaning we have to add the token to the options, not in url
      if (!options) {
        // let's make option object
        options = {headers: new Headers()};
      }
      options.headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`);
      options.headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    } else {
    // we have to add the token to the url object
      url.headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`);
      url.headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    }
    return super.request(url, options)
                .catch(this.catchAuthError(this));
  }

  private catchAuthError (self: HttpService) {
    // we have to pass HttpService's own instance here as `self`
    return (res: Response) => {
      console.log(res);
      if (res.status === 401 || res.status === 403) {
        // if not authenticated
        console.log(res);
      }
      return Observable.throw(res);
    };
  }
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
providers: [{
      provide: HttpService,
      useFactory: (backend: XHRBackend, options: RequestOptions) => {
        return new HttpService(backend, options);
      },
      deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions]
    }, LoggedInGuard, UserService],
```

**picture.service.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class PictureService {

    url: string = 'v1/pictures';

    constructor(private http: HttpService) { }

    list(): Observable<PictureComponent[]> {
         return this.http
                    .get(this.url)
                    .map(res => res.json());
    }

}
```

**Component to consume picture.service.ts**

```
@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'picture-list',
    templateUrl: './pictureList.component.html'
})
export class ListagemComponent { 

    pictures: PictureComponent[] = [];
    service: PictureService;
    msg: String = '';

    constructor(service: PictureService){
        this.service = service;
        this.service
            .list()
            .subscribe(pictures => {
                this.pictures = pictures;
            }, err => console.log(err));
    }

 }
```

thanks for help

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code. All angular http methods goes through the `request` method so I think it's impossible that it is not called.

Comment: @AdonesPitogo I used the override mentioned by mrgoos and worked very weel. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I extend XHRBackend

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Request, XHRBackend, BrowserXhr, ResponseOptions, XSRFStrategy, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';

@Injectable()
export class ExtendedXHRBackend extends XHRBackend {

  constructor(browserXhr: BrowserXhr, baseResponseOptions: ResponseOptions, xsrfStrategy: XSRFStrategy) {
    super(browserXhr, baseResponseOptions, xsrfStrategy);
  }

  createConnection(request: Request) {
    let token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    request.headers.set('x-access-token', `${token}`); 
    request.headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    let xhrConnection = super.createConnection(request);
    xhrConnection.response = xhrConnection.response.catch((error: Response) => {
      if (error.status === 401 || error.status === 403) {
        console.log('access not alowed');
        localStorage.removeItem('token');
      }
      return Observable.throw(error);
    });
    return xhrConnection;
  }
}
```

and use on app module

```
providers: [{ provide: XHRBackend, useClass: ExtendedXHRBackend }]
```

After this I resolve the issue and works preety well

Comment: Vinicius, just bear in mind that if you extend XHRBackend you will not be able to use your services since they are not inherited properly due to angular core bug, as stated in Adones blog. I just saw that on the latest RC release it's being fixed: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#230-rc0-2016-11-30

Comment: Update: in Angular 2.3.0 you can safely override the HTTP class: `{ provide: Http, useClass: ExtendedHttpService }`

Comment: @mrgoos with override the Adone code works weel! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Did you provide `picture.service` in your module? If not, you should provide it in your `@component` or in your module if you want it globally.